# scrolltop равный 0 при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы при обновлении страницы всегда показывалась самая верхняя часть сайта? Что бы браузер не пытался прокрутить сайт туда где он был перед обновлением.

Answer (score 2):

При загрузке:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
// или jQuery
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: не работает...всеравно перематывает в то место с которого обновил страницы

Comment: Значит попробуйте 

    $(window).load(function () {
       $(this).scrollTop(0);
    });

Comment: Да, я так пробовал, но чтото не хочет работать... ни каких мыслей нет? или это 100% должно работать?

Comment: работает если только таймаут поставить, даже самый маленький. Но не уверен что это корректно

Comment: Вы положили скрипт в $(document).ready ?

Comment: да, туда положил

Comment: Возможно, что браузер делает прокрутку до той точки, на которой был прекращен просмотр, по тому же событию; из-за этого и конфликт. Не задавался этим вопросом, но минимальная задержка - это тоже вариант.